# Applying for Schengen next week from US but my US visa is expiring in August. Will they accept my application?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Has anyone tried applying for Schengen from US when their US visa was going to expire within 3 months of departure from Schengen area?

Just saw this:

> The US residence permit or visa should be valid for at least three
> months beyond the intended departure from the Schengen Area.

https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-united-states/

I am on H1B visa in US which is expiring in August. I am planning to go to Italy in July 1st week and will be returning back to US mid July. My Schengen visa appointment in Boston is next week.

Give above, does it mean Italy consulate won't accept my application?

Comment: Have you checked the official site?  The site you've linked to in the question is not an official site.

Comment: thanks @phoog. can you pls pls link the official site? the one i linked is what pops everywhere on my google search.

Comment: The consular site is http://consboston.esteri.it/ but it seems to have been down for most of the day. Another official link is https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en. I don't see any information about the documents required to establish your residence in the US, which most Schengen countries do list on their US consular sites, so I've upvoted the question. It may be that Italy doesn't check this and that the third-party site has picked up the requirement from some other country that does. At this point all you can do is go to your appointment and post an answer here to tell us what happened.